# PdfLaTex: Author List Problem When Using Elsevier Template

Tags: templates, author-number, els-cas

I'm trying to use the Elsevier template from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates, but I meet a problem when I try to include more than two authors, the results become **Author1, Author2, and Author3**, but I want it to be **Author1, Author2, Author3**, is there any way to realize this? Thanks to everyone in advance.

A minimum example is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}

% \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
% \usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

% Uncomment and use as if needed
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
%\newdefinition{rmk}{Remark}
%\newproof{pf}{Proof}
%\newproof{pot}{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm}}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add

\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

% Short title
\shorttitle{A}

% Short author
\shortauthors{A et al}

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{A}
% Title footnote mark
% eg: \tnotemark[1]
% \tnotemark[1]

% Title footnote 1.
% eg: \tnotetext[1]{Title footnote text}
% \tnotetext[1]{Test}

% -------------------------------- Authors -------------------------------- %

\author[a]{AAA}[style=Chinese]

% Corresponding author indication
% \cormark[<corr mark no>]

% Footnote of the first author
% \fnmark[<footnote mark no>]

% URL of the first author
% \ead[url]{<URL>}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[a]{organization={A},
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={A},
            % state={},
            country={A}}

\author[a]{BBB}[style=Chinese]

% Footnote of the second author
\fnmark[*]

% URL of the first author
% \ead[url]{<URL>}

% Corresponding author text
\cortext[1]{Corresponding author}

% Footnote text
% \fntext[1]{}

% For a title note without a number/mark
% \nonumnote{}
\author[b]{CCC}

% Footnote of the third author
% \fnmark[*]

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[b]{organization={A},
            addressline={A},
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={A},
            % state={},
            country={A}}
            
% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
A
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}
A

% -------------------------------- Bibliography -------------------------------- %

%% Loading bibliography style file
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{refs}

% -------------------------------- End -------------------------------- %

\end{document}
```

Use the above code to replace `cas-dc-template.tex`, then it should be compiled without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added some code to your example.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%%********************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \stmauthors { } 
{
    \group_begin:
    \stmAuthorSetup { type = authors }
    \l_stm_au_setup_tl
    \par \vskip\l_stm_augroup_before_dim
    \l_stm_augroup_align_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_size_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_shape_tl
    \l_stm_augroup_weight_tl
    \color{ \l_stm_augroup_color_tl }
    \bool_if:NTF \g_stm_augr_bool
    { \seq_use:Nn \g_stm_augr_seq { \par } }
    {
        \seq_use:cnnn { g_stm_au\int_use:N\g_stm_augr_int _seq }
        { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
    }
    \par\vskip\l_stm_augroup_after_dim
    \group_end:
}   
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%********************************** 


% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}

% \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
% \usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

%\newcommand\theead { \int_use:N \g_ead_int }

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

% Uncomment and use as if needed
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
%\newdefinition{rmk}{Remark}
%\newproof{pf}{Proof}
%\newproof{pot}{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm}}

\begin{document}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add
    
    \Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
    \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
    
    \let\WriteBookmarks\relax
    \def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
    \def\textpagefraction{.001}
    
    % Short title
    \shorttitle{ Short title}
    
    % Short author
    \shortauthors{A et al}
    
    % Main title of the paper
    \title [mode = title]{ Main title of the paper}
    % Title footnote mark
    % eg: \tnotemark[1]
    % \tnotemark[1]
    
    % Title footnote 1.
    % eg: \tnotetext[1]{Title footnote text}
    % \tnotetext[1]{Test}
    
    % -------------------------------- Authors -------------------------------- %
    
    \author[a]{ Author1}[style=Chinese]
    
    % Corresponding author indication
    % \cormark[<corr mark no>]
    
    % Footnote of the first author
    % \fnmark[<footnote mark no>]
    
    % URL of the first author
    % \ead[url]{<URL>}
    
    % Address/affiliation
    \affiliation[a]{organization={AAA},
        % city={},
        % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
        postcode={A1},
        % state={},
        country={A2}}
    
    \author[a]{ Author2}[style=Chinese]
    
    % Footnote of the second author
    \fnmark[*]
    
    % URL of the first author
    % \ead[url]{<URL>}
    
    % Corresponding author text
    \cortext[1]{Corresponding author}
    
    % Footnote text
    % \fntext[1]{}
    
    % For a title note without a number/mark
    % \nonumnote{}
    \author[b]{ Author3}
    
    % Footnote of the third author
    % \fnmark[*]
    
    % Address/affiliation
    \affiliation[b]{organization={BBB},
        addressline={B1},
        % city={},
        % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
        postcode={B2},
        % state={},
        country={B3}}
    
    % -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %
    
    \begin{abstract}
    Abstract
    \end{abstract}
    
    % -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{1}
    Introduction
    
    % -------------------------------- Bibliography -------------------------------- %
    
    %% Loading bibliography style file
%   %\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
%   \bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}
%   
%   % Loading bibliography database
%   \bibliography{refs}
%   
    % -------------------------------- End -------------------------------- %
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works perfectly!